# How do I access my non-public AWS RDS MySQL database with MySQL WorkBench?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database

Trying to access my database in AWS with MySQL Work Bench, but the only way I'm able to access it is by making the database public and open to all inbound traffic. This is a huge security risk and I do not want to do this.

I've tried adding my IP to my RDS security group, but still, I'm not able to connect to my Database through MySql Workbench.

Comment: Set up a VPN between your network / workstation (AWS client VPN client software on your PC might be easiest) and your AWS VPC, then allow access to MySQL from the VPC. You'll end up paying for a VPG in your VPC. Alternately allow public access to your RDS instance but set up security groups to whitelist your IP (free).

Answer (score 0):

To connect to AWS RDS MySQL instance without publicly exposing the RDS instance, you can configure MySQL Workbench to connect via SSH[1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-ssh.html). This requires a Bastion host allowing SSH into the VPC and the ingress security group attached to your RDS instance to allow SSH.